# Не до конца скрываются строки таблицы

Tags: javascript, html, css, table

Решил сделать таблицу, у которой при нажатии кнопки показываются/скрываются строки. Всё работает хорошо, но есть одна маленькая неприятная проблема - когда строки скрываются, то там остаётся расстояние в несколько пикселей.

[image: Таблица]

Попробовал добавить *display: none;* к **#tchests tr.hidden td** , но тогда не будет работать *transition*. Итоговый код гораздо больше, и всё завязано на тег **table**, поэтому предложение переверстать всё на **div**-ах мне не подходит.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page</title>
  <style type="text/css">
        #tchests { width: 25%; border-collapse: collapse; }

        #tchests th, #tchests td { text-align: center; border-style: solid; border-color: #dcdcdc; }
        #tchests tr.show-more td { cursor: pointer; border-top-width: 0; }

        #tchests tr.hidden td { padding: 0; border-width: 0; overflow: hidden; transition: border-width 0s .50s linear, padding 0s .50s linear; }
        #tchests tr.visible td { padding: 7px 8px; border-width: 3px; transition: padding .25s linear; }

        #tchests tr.hidden td div { max-height: 0; transition: max-height .50s linear; }
        #tchests tr.visible td div { max-height: 100px; transition: max-height .75s linear; }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
      document.querySelector('#tchests tr.show-more').onclick = function() {
        let els = document.querySelectorAll('#tchests tr.hidden');
        if (els.length > 0) {
          for (let i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
            els[i].classList.remove('hidden');
            els[i].classList.add('visible');
          }
        } else {
          let els = document.querySelectorAll('#tchests tr.visible');
          for (let i = els.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            els[i].classList.remove('visible');
            els[i].classList.add('hidden');
          }
        }
      };
    };
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="tchests">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="top">
        <th>A</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>1</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="hidden">
        <td>
          <div>2</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="hidden">
        <td>
          <div>3</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="show-more">
        <td colspan="3"><span>Show/Hide</span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такой артефакт, как неполное схлопование ячеек и строк с нулевой высотой,   проявляется только в браузере Firefox, при:

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
```

Если выставить:

```css
table { border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 0px; }
```

то проблема решается.

В Chrome, Edge и прочих *chromium* (Safari и IE нет возможности проверить) указанных отступов не наблюдается и работают оба варианта.

*Боюсь, что это "плавающий" баг от версии к версии, причём во всех браузерах. ИМХО.*

Для решения вопроса, фиксим баг, как описано выше, и выключаем у всех ячеек одну из сторон *border*-а — *top* или *bottom*:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Page</title>
  <style>
    #tchests { width: 25%; border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 0px; }    
    #tchests th, #tchests td { text-align: center; border-style: solid; border-color: #dcdcdc; }
    #tchests tbody tr td { padding: 0; border-width: 0; overflow: hidden; transition: border-width 0s .50s linear, padding 0s .5s linear;}
    #tchests tbody.visible tr td { padding: 7px 8px; border-width: 3px; border-top-width: 0; transition: padding .25s linear; }
    #tchests tbody tr td div { max-height: 0; transition: max-height .5s linear; }    
    #tchests tbody.visible tr td div { max-height: 100px; transition: max-height .75s linear; }
    #tchests tfoot tr td { cursor: pointer; border-width: 3px; border-top-width: 0; }
  </style>
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      document.querySelector('#tchests tfoot tr').onclick = () => {
        document.querySelector('#tchests tbody').classList.toggle('visible');
      };
    };
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <table id="tchests">
    <thead><tr><th>A</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td><div>1</div></td></tr>
      <tr><td><div>2</div></td></tr>
      <tr><td><div>3</div></td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot><tr><td><span>Show/Hide</span></td></tr></tfoot>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: У меня в Firefox85 ваш код даёт ту же проблему. Возможно, вы не слишком внимательно присмотрелись к своему результату. Например, откройте две одинаковые вкладки с работой вашего кода (где первая вкладка - вы ничего не трогаете, а вторая - это после того, как вы нажали Show/Hide), и сравните.

Comment: @МихаилТестов: кажется нашёл причину. Только в FF такая трабла. Ща разберёмся...

Comment: спасибо большое, работает как надо. Если вдруг имеете возможность, то напишите, пожалуйста, хотя бы кратко, что явилось причиной данной проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Все очень просто. При `border-style: collapse` даже скрытые строки/ячейки имеют свой бордюр. Так что, скрывать их надо `display: none` или использовать выборочный бордюр `border-style: separate;` со свойствами `cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    #tchests {
      width: 25%;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    
    #tchests th,
    #tchests td {
      text-align: center;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: #dcdcdc;
    }
    
    #tchests tr.show-more td {
      cursor: pointer;
      border-top-width: 0;
    }
    
    #tchests tr.hidden td {
      padding: 0;
      border-width: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: border-width 0s .50s linear, padding 0s .50s linear;
    }
    
    #tchests tr.visible td {
      padding: 7px 8px;
      border-width: 3px;
      transition: padding .25s linear;
    }
    
    #tchests tr.hidden td div {
      max-height: 0;
      transition: max-height .50s linear;
    }
    
    #tchests tr.visible td div {
      max-height: 100px;
      transition: max-height .75s linear;
    }
    
    #tchests tr.invisible td {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
      document.querySelector('#tchests tr.show-more').onclick = function() {
        let els = document.querySelectorAll('#tchests tr.hidden');
        if (els.length > 0) {
          for (let i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
            els[i].classList.remove('invisible');
            els[i].classList.remove('hidden');
            els[i].classList.add('visible');
          }
        } else {
          let els = document.querySelectorAll('#tchests tr.visible');
          for (let i = els.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            els[i].classList.remove('visible');
            els[i].classList.add('hidden');
          }
          setTimeout(() => {
            [...document.querySelectorAll('#tchests tr.hidden')].
            map(tr => tr.classList.add('invisible'));
          }, 500);
        }
      };
    };
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="tchests">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="top">
        <th>A</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>1</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="hidden">
        <td>
          <div>2</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="hidden">
        <td>
          <div>3</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="show-more">
        <td colspan="3"><span>Show/Hide</span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```